# LogManager getProperty MyClass.filter in java

Tags: java, logging, filter, getproperty

I have create the following code in java :

```
LogManager manager = LogManager.getLogManager();
String className = this.getClass().getName();
String level = manager.getProperty(className + ".filter");
```

nevertheless, the variable is null after the call to getProperty, but className has the name : "view.frame.WindowHandler"

Any ideas ? Thank you very much

Comment: Your code says `".filter"`, shouldn't it say `".level"`? [This doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) seems to indicate that the log level should be in the `{loggerName}.level` property.

Comment: me I see that : "A property config.... such as setting logger levels, adding handlers, adding filters, etc"  I took the code from this url : (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/WindowHandlerdisplaylogmessageinawindowJFrame.htm)

Comment: Yeah, the code on the Java2S page uses `".level"` too. Is this a typo on your part?

Comment: Also, are you sure you've added the filter or the level to the logger? Either via `Logger#setLevel()` or `Logger#setFilter()`, or (in the case of the level) from the configuration file?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake on the link, that is the good link : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/JavalogLogandWindowJFrameframe.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define an entry that is loaded by the [LogManager configuration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#a1.8).  The default logging configuration file located in `lib/logging.properties` in the JRE directory. Add the following entries to the `logging.properties` file:

```
#WindowHandler settings
view.frame.WindowHandler.level = INFO
view.frame.WindowHandler.filter = some.filter.class.Name
```

You should create your own `logging.properties` file and set the [java.util.logging.config.file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html) system property to configure the LogManager for your application.